# Picasso is not loading image if I use resize() function

Tags: android, picasso

When I load a file using picasso with resize option, it doesn't show up. I'm using `Picasso.with(mContext).load(file).resize(160,213).into(holder.skinImage);`

The file has dimension of 4608 X 3456. It loads up when I use Picasso without resize but it takes too long to load.
`Picasso.with(mContext).load(file).into(holder.skinImage);`

**EDIT:** I just tried loading image of size 1080 X 1920 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Is there any error in the `LogCat`?

Comment: @RaymondLukanta no error

Comment: resizing after downloading the `4608 X 3456` image is not going to help improve the download speed

Comment: What version of picasso are you using?

Comment: @JohnWowUs version 2.5

Comment: I'd suggest trying the latest version 2.5.2.

Comment: @JohnWowUs Done. Not even this version working on high resolution images

Comment: too long is how long, can you tell more?

Answer (score 0):

Strange for me that you say that with no resizing downloading takes more time - it should take exact the same time.

Resizing with Picasso `.resize()` is bad if you planning to obtain that image anywhere else with no resizing, since it will be cached with some `-resize-160,213` prefix and when you will try to obtain it via just URL you'll get cache miss. So why not resize by XML layout argument?

Also you can [enable Http logging](https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-cache-indicators-logging-stats) to see, whats going on under the hood. At least you will see, if it's `not downloaded` or `not placed` (and see the cache inside picasso instance - is it picture there or not?). If you find out the second option - try to change layout.

Comment: I'm loading it from local file. I just tried to load the same image in Target variable and onBitmapFailed() fired with errorDrawable null.

Comment: Are you sure you don't change anything else except adding resize() ?

Comment: Yeah. Actually it works fine when i load image of size 1080 X 1920

Comment: Do you use OpenGL ? It comes with its max image size limits. Maybe you faced with some android memory limit. Try to setup largeHeap into manifest. Or try to load it directly from resources into ImageView:src (just to be sure that it's not a some size/memory limit). Maybe this also will help https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Could you try using `.fit()` instead of using `.resize()`?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add scaletype like this

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(file).resize(160,213).centerCrop().into(holder.skinImage);
```